# Last Index Of a Number in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, search

Given an array of length N and an integer x, you need to find and return the last index of integer x present in the array. Return -1 if it is not present in the array.

Last index means - if x is present multiple times in the array, return the index at which x comes last in the array.

You should start traversing your array from 0, not from (N - 1).
Do this recursively. Indexing in the array starts from 0.

Input Format :

```
Line 1 : An Integer N i.e. size of array
Line 2 : N integers which are elements of the array, separated by spaces
Line 3 : Integer x

Output Format :
last index or -1

Constraints :
1 <= N <= 10^3

Sample Input :
4
9 8 10 8
8

Sample Output :
3
```

Basically we are supposed to do this recursively can anyone verify my code whether I have done it correctly using recursion or not

```java
    public class Solution {
         static int idx = -1;
         static int helper(int input[], int x ,int i){
            if(i == input.length){
            return idx;
            }
            else if(input[i] == x){
              if(i > idx ){
                idx = i;
             }
           }
        return helper(input,x,i +1);
    }

    public static int lastIndex(int input[], int x) {
        /* Your class should be named Solution
         * Don't write main().
         * Don't read input, it is passed as function argument.
         * Return output and don't print it.
         * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
        */
        return helper(input,x,0);
    }
}
```

Comments have come with the question itself

Comment: Don't store `idx` in a static field. This should be another parameter of `helper`.

Comment: @AndyTurner like what is wrong with using idx as a static variable

Comment: @JavvajiLokesh think about what happens if you run the method a second time; or on multiple threads in parallel.

Comment: @user16320675 not necessarily. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206341/last-index-of-a-number-in-an-array?noredirect=1#comment122320176_69206341).

Comment: @AndyTurner u mean like using the same idx in a different method

Comment: Is the helper method signature part of the requirements? Does it have to be `helper(int[], int, 0);` or are you permitted to change it)?

Answer (score 1):

as Andy stated you should had put `idx` as a param in your `helper` and `lastIndex` functions , and initiate that param with -1 for every invokation of `lastIndex`. Because with the way you doing things until now , let's suppose that the `lastIndex` is invoked for the first time , and altered the value of idx to 8 ( because for the first array you've passed the index is 8 ) . After that you re-invoke the same method but this time with an array which length is smaller than 8 ; `i` will never be bigger than `idx` , and thus the result returned this time will be wrong ( 8 ).
Note also the `if(i > idx )` check is not necessary , because you're always passing `i+1` to the next call and thus `i` will always be greater than `idx`.

```
public class Solution {
    static int helper(int input[], int x ,int i, int idx){
        if(i == input.length){
            return idx;
        }
        else if(input[i] == x){
                idx = i;
        }
        return helper(input,x,i +1,idx);
    }

    public static int lastIndex(int input[], int x) {
        /* Your class should be named Solution
         * Don't write main().
         * Don't read input, it is passed as function argument.
         * Return output and don't print it.
         * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
         */
        return helper(input,x,0,-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: we cannot invoke the last index function question itself was framed in that manner

Comment: @JavvajiLokesh , I don't get what you mean. If for whatever reason all you care about is the logic inside your help function it is correct. But soon or later lastIndex should be called otherwise what's the point of creating programs without executing them. And when lastIndex is invoked , you'll have the problem that I've stated earlier.

Comment: The `if(i > idx )` check is not necessary, it's always going to be true (yes, I see it was there in the question already, but still)

Comment: @tevemadar yes you have a point. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
static int idx = -1;
```

This is a bad idea, because it's global mutable state.

Let's say the first thing your `main` method did was to invoke `lastIndex(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5)`: you'd get the result 4, as expected.

But then, what if you invoked `lastIndex(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 1)`? You'd get the result 4 again. Huh?

This is because you didn't reset `idx` after you ran `lastIndex`. You could reset it before you first call `helper`:

```
public static int lastIndex(int input[], int x) {
  idx = -1;
  return helper(input, x, 0);
}
```

but you've still got the problem that something else (another thread) can come along and reset it as well: you might get the right answer; you might get -1; you might get the intermediate or final result from another thread's `lastIndex` invocation.

This is all easily avoidable by *not* having a static field `idx`: pass it as an additional parameter to `helper`. Because method parameters are effectively local variables, these are stack-confined, so there is no risk of seeing another thread's `idx` value.

```
static int helper(int input[], int x ,int i, int idx){
  // ...
}

public static int lastIndex(int input[], int x) {
  return helper(input, x, 0, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you can't change the helper method signature and arguments since it appears to be a requirement.  But you can satisfy the primary method and helper method arguments by doing it as follows:

```
public static int lastIndex(int[] input, int x) {
    if (input == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    return helper(input, x, 0);
}
    
public static int helper(int[] input, int x, int i) {
    if (i == input.length) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (input[input.length-i-1] == x) {
           return input.length-i-1;
    }
    return helper(input, x, i+1);       
}
```

Unfortunately, even though the index is incremented, this is checking the array in reverse which was also taboo.  If it is run by an automated system it would probably pass since it meets the helper signature.  If it is scrutinized by a human, probably not.